# android addTextChangedListener not fully deleting the text in Firebase when backspace

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, addtextchangedlistener

I was facing the problem with the addTextChangedListener that was not fully delete the text in Firebase. I state an example, I get my name from Firebase and `setText()` on the `myname`. So on `myname` editText has show my name there. When I wanted to edit, I click on editText, so I can remove the word by backspace, but when I backspace too fast, the text in editText was fully removed (client side) and there are some word did not delete on Firebase(server side).

Which mean the removing text value are not consistent and accurate with the client side and server side. The ordinary text of my name is Tommy, so I backspace until the Tommy word gone, so that was cleared but in Firebase it still showing the first character 'T' of my name.

But when I was clearing all word on the editText, I input new word such as "Hello", the Firebase will store Hello.

**Code:**

```
 //delcare myname
 private MultiAutoCompleteTextView myname;

 myname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(!myname.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                DatabaseReference nameRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child(Config.URL_USER);
                nameRef.child(uid).child("myName").setValue(userET.getText().toString());

                parentActivity.updateHeaderUserName(myname.getText().toString());
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This loops work until there is a single charcter in the edittext, so add an else loop and inside the else loops set the value as null